# EE 2.7 / Krea Content Elements 1.5.5: Rich Text formating Buttons missing after updating

Tags: richtext, content-elements

After updating EE from 2.6.1 to 2.7. the Content Elements Richtext-field lost the formatting buttons. I updated CE to 1.5.5 but the buttons are still missing.
When I add a standard EE Richtext field the buttons are available.
I installed and uninstalled CE but that didn´t help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with format buttons not showing on the front end of my Channel Forms, latest release needs you to render the css file on your site, maybe this is the issue as I assume CE will need to release an update to ensure this is picked up also.